# Using an Array as the Key for an Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

I need to create an association between an Array and a Number; as PHP lacks a Map type, I am trying using an array to achieve this:

```
$rowNumberbyRow = array();
$rowNumberByRow[$rowData] = $rowNumber;
```

However, when I evaluate the code, I get the following Error:

`Warning: Illegal offset type`

Just to note, the data stored in the array (`$rowData`) does not have any 'unique' values that I can use as a key for the `$rowNumberByRow` Array.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** 
To answer some of my commenters, I am trying to create a [lookup table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) so that my application can find the row number for a given row in O(1) time.

Comment: `$rowNumberByRow [ $rowData ['your_key'] ] = $rowNumber;`

Comment: @Jacek_FH I'm trying to create a lookup table so I can retrieve the rowNumber for a given row.

Comment: @bensiu - as I said in the question, none of the fields in $rowData are unique enough to use as keys ;)

Comment: Made something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047903/complex-type-as-array-index/4053754#4053754

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP does have a map Class: It's called [SplObjectStorage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php). It can be accessed with exactly the same syntax as a general array is (see Example #2 on [the reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php)).

But to use the class you will have to use [the ArrayObject class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) instead of arrays. It is handled exactly the same way arrays are and you can construct instances from arrays (e.g. `$arrayObject = new ArrayObject($array)`).

If you don't want to use those classes, you can also just create a function that creates unique hash-strings for your indexes. For example:

```
function myHash($array){
   return implode('|',$array);
}
$rowNumberByRow[myHash($array)] = $rowNumber;
```

You will of course have to make sure that your hashes are indeed unique, and I would strongly suggest you use the SplObjectStorage and maybe read a little bit more about the SPL classes of php.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about these classes!

Comment: I forgot to mention: SplObjectStorage will index by Instance, not by Object content, so you would have to hold on to your ArrayObjects. If you want a content-based map, you will have to write a hash function, as outlined in the second part of my answer.

Comment: There is absolutely no requirement to use `ArrayObject` at all, a boring old `stdClass` would do just as well for the map.

Comment: If you can hold onto the instances you might as well just store the row number in the original array, and save the object overhead and hash lookup.

Comment: @salathe PHP throws the following warning when I try to assign an array as a key -- `Warning: SplObjectStorage::offsetSet() expects parameter 1 to be object, array`

Comment: @JonnyReeves, take heed of the class name... Spl **Object** Storage.

Comment: @salathe Sorry, I thought your original comment implied I didn't have to wrap my Array's in ArrayObject instances.

Comment: @JonnyReeves, you don't. However, you also can't use plain `array`s.

Comment: @JonnyReeves - did you notice Chronial's comment regarding instances vs. content?

Comment: @Long Ears, Yes I did, I found it alien that PHP does not treat an Array in the same way it would treat an instance.  zerkms answer that array's can only store scalar values nails it for me - I ended up just computing a hash for each Array to use as the key.

Comment: @JonnyReeves the point was that although you could cast your array to an object and use SplObjectStorage, it would require the same object, not just an object with the same properties. I'm still curious if that's applicable, why you couldn't just store the row number in the array. Anyway, if you're using a custom hash function (especially if wrapped in another function like suggested), and you're concerned about performance, do compare it against serialize...

Comment: @Long Ears, The `$rowData` is also being stored in a sequential List (using an array), the `$rowNumberByRow` array simply acts as a lookup table.  I don't want to augment the `$row` array with a `rowNumber` property as it is only an association.  Maybe I am abusing array's where I would be using Object literals in JS / AS.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just store the row number in the array? e.g:

```
$rowData['rowNumber'] = $rowNumber;
```

You could instead serialize the array, e.g:

```
$rowNumberByRow[serialize($rowData)] = $rowNumber;
```

However that's pretty inefficient.

Comment: Yeah, that crossed my mind, but I came to the same conclusion - it's a pretty poor way of trying to implement a lookup table :(

Answer (score 1):

In php you can use only scalar values as array keys.

If your `$rowNumber` is unique - then you'd try to use the opposite relation direction. If it is not unique - then you don't have any possible solution I know.